# Is it possible to somehow get copy #2 in the ERC 1155 NFT contract under ID 1?

Tags: node.js, web3js, erc1155

For example:
I released NFT with ID 1 in the amount of 100 pieces.
Someone bought 2 copies. Can I somehow get a copy under #2 ?

I am using nodeJS and web3. I can only get the total number of copies with

```
const nftId = 1;
contract.methods.balanceOf(address, nftId).call();
```

Can you tell me if my idea is feasible or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I googled and found a similar question on Reddit. Answer: it's impossible.